# Regular expression to get/store row count from SQL query output

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regular expression, and the reading I have done has not got me going enough.  What I'm trying to do is extract the row count output from a SQL query.  For example, if either of the examples below appear as the output, I want to capture the value to the left of the '(', so '0', '92', or any other number.

Can any regex experts out there help me out please!

The output that would be captured is from running a .sql file from the command line:

Changed database context to 'mydb'.           -----------          0(1 rows affected)

Changed database context to 'mydb'.           -----------         92(1 rows affected)

Here is the code that is partially working - it's getting the row count with leading spaces that can be trimmed...just don't know if this is the best code.

```
Process execQuery = new Process();
string output = "";    
string argumentsToPass = "-S myhost -d mydb -i + sqlFileToExecute;

execQuery.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
execQuery.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
execQuery.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlcmd";
execQuery.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentsToPass;
execQuery.Start();
execQuery.WaitForExit();
output = execQuery.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Match match = Regex.Match(output, @"\s+\d+");
```

Comment: Where are you getting these row counts from? You can get the count of rows matching a query directly from SQL, or the number of rows affected by a command directly in .NET, you don't need to mess around with strings or regular expressions at all. Show us your code.

Comment: @DourHighArch is on the right track -- Regex is not the right solution to this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181583/mysql-return-number-of-rows-matching-query-data

Comment: @erman8, can you explain what outcome you are trying to achieve? That code you posted makes no sense; what is `sqlFileToExecute`? If you want to run a SQL file, you can do that directly from the command-line, or from a shortcut. Why are you creating a C# program? If you need to run a query from C# why not use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`? What are you going to be doing with the "row count output" from your query? That code throws the result away, so I don't understand what you're trying to do at all.

Comment: 'sqlFileToExecute' is a .sql file that is passed into a method.  The idea was to compare the actual row count of a query to the expected row count.  The code shown reports the query results as 'Changed database context to 'mydb'. ----------- 92(1 rows affected)', not just the count.
Please provide an example of what you mean.  The code is done in C# because it is part of test case setup for QA.

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this would work:

```
(\d{1,})(\()
```

There are two matching groups here, the first will return the number you are interested in. This pattern basically matches any number sitting to the left of an open bracket.

Here is the usage in code:

```
regex.match(myOutputString, "(\d{1,})(\()").groups(1).tostring
```

Also check this out, if you're learning:

[Online tool for testing Regular Expressions](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 0):

For some direction, i love this c# regex sheet http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

In plain english, what your goal should be is probably to locate the last hyphen (-), then grab any digits until you see an open parenthesis.

Good Luck!